# Intermittent ClassNotFoundException with PageLink

Tags: 2013, classnotfoundexception

We are running a .Net website based on SDL Tridion 2013. We are getting intermittent ClassNotFoundException from PageLink. Below is the stacktrace from the exception.

> Exception information:
>
> Exception type: Exception
>
> Exception message: com.tridion.linking.PageLink
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.linking.PageLink
>
> at com.codemesh.classloader.ExtensibleClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.codemesh.classloader.ExtensibleClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.codemesh.classloader.ExtensibleClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.codemesh.bootstrap.JarInputStreamBootstrapper.forName(Unknown Source)
>
> at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
>
> at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
>
> at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
>
> at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init()
>
> at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject()
>
> at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
>
> at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr()
>
> at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle()
>
> at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
>
> at Com.Tridion.Linking.PageLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId)
>
> at ASP.error_pages_server_error_aspx..ctor()
>
> at __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_server_error_aspx_8307e16d_x5schrje.Create_ASP_error_pages_server_error_aspx()
>
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance()
>
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
>
> at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>
> at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
>
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

This error shows randomly once a day and then restarting IIS resolves the error. We are using the 32 bit version of Tridion runtime libraries for the presentation side. The version of Java on the presentation server is 1.7u40. Please advice.

Comment: Hi, Did you get any resolution for your issue, we are also facing the same issue.

Comment: @rdhaundiyal No resolution yet.

Comment: Are all messages for java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on com.tridion.linking.PageLink or do you see this come up for other classes as well?

Answer (score 1):

Check the step no 21 on [Tridion documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14)
which talk about disable recycling of the Application Pool, though this has not resolved our issue completely but the frequency has reduced and we are still monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you are using correct version of xmogrt.dll file.
Note: The file size of the 64 version is 1,123kb, the 32bit version is less.

Comment: checked the filesize of xmorgrt.dll. It is 900kb (x86 version).